# SQL group payments by user and keep track of last date_paid?

Tags: mysql, sql

Ok so I have a users table and a payments table.  Each payment has a date_paid and amount_paid.  I would like to group the payments by the sum of the amount paid, but I would also like to keep a field for a last date_paid.  Is this possible?  Or will I have to store a last_date_paid column within the user table?

Comment: max(date_paid) will give you the last date paid

Comment: @blacktie24 . . . What you want to do is unclear to me ("group the payments by the sum of the amount paid" . . . what does that mean?).  Can yo provide sample data and expected results?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT id, SUM(amount_paid), MAX(date_paid)
FROM payments
GROUP BY id
```